# How can I run a exponential regression in R with an annotated regression equation in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, exponential

I have created a normal bivariate dataset with a strong linear association below:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Create Data ####
x <- rnorm(n=1000, mean=120, sd=15)
y <- 4*x + 5 + rnorm(n=1000, mean = 0, sd = 5)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

#### Plot ####
ggplot(df,
       aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")

#### Run Regression ####
lm.xy <- lm(y~x,
            data = df)
summary(lm.xy)
```

Which gives me what I want, a linear relationship and a model that fits (the R2 is understandably above 90%):

[image]

I have tried to do the same thing with exponential data like so:

```
#### Create Exponential Data ####
x2 <- dexp(1:50, rate=.1)*1000
y2 <- dexp(1:50, rate=.8)*1000
df2 <- data.frame(x2,y2)

#### Plot ####
ggplot(df2,
       aes(x=x2,
           y=y2))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()
```

Plotting this, there is no issue:

[image]

However, I'm not sure how to model this with a regression. If I do the typical regression formula:

```
#### Run Regression ####
exp.reg <- lm(y2 ~ x2,
              df2)
summary(exp.reg)
```

It will understandably have a much less precise model:

```
Residual standard error: 42.66 on 48 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4305,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4187 
F-statistic: 36.29 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 2.302e-07
```

Additionally, I tried labeling the regression equation to the plot:

```
ggplot(df2,
       aes(x=x2,
           y=y2))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()+
  stat_regline_equation(aes(exp.reg))
```

But this gave me an error:

```
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (50): x
```

So my question has two parts. First, how do I model an exponential regression properly? Second, how do I annotate that regression equation onto ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

1. In your exponential data example, `geom_smooth` without additional arguments fits a [LOESS model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression). So this is probably not what you want.
2. Note that your exponential data is linear on a log-scale.

Now as to how to fit a model: We can fit a linear model to the log-transformed data.

```r
# Fit a linear model
fit <- lm(log(y2) ~ log(x2), data = df2)

# Create `data.frame` with predictions
df_predict <- data.frame(x2 = seq(min(df2$x2), max(df2$x2), length.out = 1000))
df_predict$y2_pred = exp(predict(fit, newdata = df_predict))

# Plot
ggplot(df2, aes(x = x2, y = y2)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line(data = df_predict, aes(y = y2_pred))
```

[image]

The coefficients of `fit` are

```r
summary(fit)$coefficients
#             Estimate   Std. Error       t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) -30.15675 7.152374e-16 -4.216327e+16        0
#log(x2)       8.00000 2.848167e-16  2.808824e+16        0
#Warning message:
#    In summary.lm(fit) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

Note the warning which is due to the way that you generated data from `dexp` (without any errors).

Also note the slope estimate (on the log scale) of 8.0, which is just the ratio of your two `dexp` rate parameters 0.8/0.1.

Comment: The log-log regression makes total sense. A couple questions: 1) why is `geom_line` superior to `geom_smooth` in this sense? As far as I'm aware, loess is just a series of local regressions pieced together. 2) What is the rationale for plotting fitted data versus the actual raw y valuers?

Comment: 1) No real advantage other than fitting a model manually and then plotting estimates allows for greater flexibility than `geom_smooth`. 2) Not sure what you mean. This is exactly what `geom_smooth` does. Plot fitted data on top of your actuals.

Comment: PS. LOESS regression is a form of non-parametric regression. Your data generation process is parametric by definition (exponential data), so why choose a non-parametric model?

Comment: Yes, I've learned before that it is non-parametric. My reasoning was that OLS would not fit this at all (the "lm" argument in `geom_smooth`), so I picked loess by default. Having understood your explanation, I can see where that's erroneous now.

Comment: `lm` will fit this just fine with `log(y) ~ log(x)`. This is still a linear model with OLS estimates. Keep in mind that the linear in "linear model" refers to coefficients being linear (not the data).